# HTML input element won't match pattern

Tags: html, forms, validation, input

I am having issues with getting a "Phone Number" input validated. I have written the regex pattern to require 10 numbers, but even when I plug in 10 numbers into the input field, I still get the error message: *"Please match the requested format"* and can't seem to figure out why this is.

All help and advice is greatly appreciated!

```
<input type="text" id="number" name="number" pattern="/^\d{10}$/" required>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code example from this page: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

You can directly do it with an in-build functionality of HTML.
Just use the type `type="tel"` and you should be good to go.
if you want 10 consecutive numbers without `-` you can also do: `pattern="[0-9]{10}"`

```
<form>
         <label for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label>
         <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}">
</form>
```

Just place you're input in a `<form>` and hit submit. It should now match.

Comment: you are awesome!! Thank you for the tip on using "tel" for the type

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need the forward slashes in your regex pattern here.
Try this:
`<input type="text" id="number" name="number" pattern="^\d{10}$" required>`

Comment: Thank you so much! I kept looking at the formats for the patterns and somehow missed no forward slashes were needed